# left and right adjoints to an order preserving functors (maps)

Tags: category-theory

$f\colon K\to L$ is a map of sets,and $f^*\colon \mathcal {P}(L)\to\mathcal{P}(K)$ is a functor sending a subset $S$ of $L$ to to its inverse image $f^{-1}(S)$. I need to find left and right adjoints to $f^*$.

Right adjoints: Functor $G\colon \mathcal{P}(K)\to\mathcal {P}(L)$ is a right adjoint to $f^*$ iff there exist natural transformations $\eta\colon 1_{\mathcal {P}(L)}\to Gf^*$ and $\epsilon:f^*G\to1_{\mathcal{P}(K)}$ satisfying triangle identities. This holds iff $S\subseteq G(f^{-1}(S))$ for every $S\subseteq L$ and $f^{-1}((G(T))\subseteq T$ for every $T\subseteq K$.

Am I correct? Can I say something more about right adjoints?

Comment: What you wrote is correct (there are also monotonicity constraints), but I would recommend you take the $\mathsf{Hom}(f^*(S),T)\cong\mathsf{Hom}(S,G(T))$ view which, in the preorder case, works out to be $f^*(S)\subseteq T\iff S\subseteq G(T)$. With this you can apply set-theoretic equivalences to turn the left hand side into the form of the right hand side, and thus find out what $G$ is. You can then check monotonicity.

Comment: How can I turn right hand side of your equivalence into the form of right hand side since $f^*(S)\subseteq T\Leftrightarrow f^{-1}(S)\subseteq T$ is not equivalent with $S\subseteq f(T)$?

Comment: The right adjoint of $f^*$ isn't the direct image of $f$. You need to calculate what $G$ is. (Incidentally, the *left* adjoint of $f^*$ is the direct image of $f$, and you can calculate that too from a symmetric equivalence.)

Comment: I've got it. We have that $G(T)=L\setminus f(K\setminus T)$?

Comment: I believe that works out and is like treating $\forall$ as $\neg\exists\neg$. An equivalent expression is $G(T)=\{l\in L\mid f^{-1}(\{l\})\subseteq T\}$.